# XSLT Select node at current level different attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, metadata, dublin-core

I'm trying to find the most elegant way to create date range based on begin and end dates. I have the following XML:

```
<mods:originInfo>
    <mods:dateCreated point="start">2006</mods:dateCreated>
    <mods:dateCreated point="end">2007</mods:dateCreated>
    <mods:dateCaptured point="start">2009</mods:dateCaptured>
    <mods:dateCaptured point="end">2010</mods:dateCaptured>
</mods:originInfo>
```

I have an XSLT that includes

```
<xsl:template match="mods:originInfo">
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*[@point='start']">
        <dc:date>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>-<xsl:value-of select="../*[local-name()][@point='end']"/>
        </dc:date>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
<dc:date>2006-2007</dc:date>
<dc:date>2009-2007</dc:date>
```

I'm trying to find a way to have this code choose the correct "end" node value. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One single modification: replace `../` with `following-sibling::` and it should work:

```
<xsl:template match="mods:originInfo">
  <xsl:for-each select="child::*[@point='start']">
    <dc:date>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>-<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[local-name()][@point='end'][1]"/>
    </dc:date>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

```
<dc:date xmlns:dc="dc">2006-2007</dc:date>
<dc:date xmlns:dc="dc">2009-2010</dc:date>
```

Comment: So simple. Confirmed to work. Thank you so much for your help!